# CSS percentage positioning of parent not grandparent

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an element inside of a parent inside of a grandparent. I am attempting to place the element halfway down the parent element using `position: absolute` and `top: 50%`. However, the element appears 50% of the way down the grandparent element instead. Why is this?

Here is my Sass:

```
#cons
  background: #242424
  border-right: 1px solid white
  width: $leftwidth
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
  height: calc(100% - 81px)
  overflow-y: scroll
#cons > li
  width: 100%
  height: 50px
  background-color: #212121
  border-bottom: 1px solid white
  display: block
#cons > li img
  width: 40px
  height: 40px
  border-radius: 40px
  margin: 0
  margin-top: 25px
  transform: translateY(-50%)
  display: inline
#cons > li span
  display: inline
  height: 5px
  position: absolute
  top: 50%
```

Here is my Pug:

```
ul(id='cons')
      li
        img(src='download.jpg')
        span Hello World
```

The element that I am trying to centre is the span element saying Hello World

Comment: please post your compiled CSS and HTML.

Comment: if you set parent to position:relative, it will be the reference, else it is the closest parent positioned, here html by defaut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positioning context of a positioned element (`absolute`/`relative`/`fixed`/s`ticky` - all except `static`) is the closest parent with position other than `static` (the default). Set `position: relative` on the `li`:

```
#cons > li
  position: relative
  width: 100%
  height: 50px
  background-color: #212121
  border-bottom: 1px solid white
  display: block
```